# How do I create a Unordered list in html with sub arrows?

Tags: css, html, wordpress, html-lists

I want to know how to accomplish something similar to this in wordpress. Any suggestions? maybe a sample code.

[image]

Can you show me an example how to apply it to the sub bullets?

Comment: I didnt get you please be clear

Comment: Maybe your sample code?

Comment: http://www.artishock.net/coding/css-list-styling-using-ascii-special-characters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup.  Use CSS, list-style-image.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp

Answer (score 3):

You could use `li:before{ content:"....";}` to make an arrow? Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Disaster</li>
    <ul>
        <li>stuff</li>
        <li>Stuff2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul ul li:before {

         content: "\2192 \0020";
}
ul ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

See it in function here, on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9AzK/

Answer (score 3):

Use `li:before { content: ...; }`

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Disater Assistance Center Manager
        <ul id="sub">
            <li>San Jaun</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#sub { list-style:none; }
#sub li:before {
    content: "\2192 \0020";
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dschu012/G7TgR/)

Other special characters can be found [here](http://www.artishock.net/coding/css-list-styling-using-ascii-special-characters/).