# Unordered list with arrows for some elements

Tags: css

I need arrows for some elements in an unordered HTML list like this:
[image]

I know how to get this with ul { list-style: none; } and ul li:before{ ... } in CSS for the whole list.
But I need this for only some elements in the same list.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML & CSS?

Comment: Do you know in advance which elements, is it a fixed list?

Comment: @15Rabi this works for whole list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21194823/4928433.

Comment: @prettyInPink yes it is a fixed list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS has the [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) pseudo element for this, which is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/css-marker-pseudo) except in any version of Internet Explorer.

```css
.arrow::marker {
  content: "⇾";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First
  <li>Second
  <li class="arrow">Third
  <li>Fourth
  <li class="arrow">Fifth
</ul>
```

If you cannot change the HTML and add thus, cannot add the `arrow` class, **and** the list has fixed content that won't change over time, you can work with `nth-child()` selectors:

```css
:is(li:nth-child(3), li:nth-child(5))::marker {
  content: "⇾";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First
  <li>Second
  <li>Third
  <li>Fourth
  <li>Fifth
</ul>
```

Note: [The `:is(...selectors)` selector is also, while almost unknown, widely supported](https://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo).

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned that you know in advance which elements, you could add `class="sub"` to them.

```css
.sub { list-style:none; }
.sub:before {
    content: "\2192 \0020";
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>This</li>
    <li>Is</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li class="sub">Unordered</li>
    <li class="sub">List</li>
</ul>
```

// Answer based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194633/how-do-i-create-a-unordered-list-in-html-with-sub-arrows/21194823#21194823), All that was needed to be changed is from

`#sub li:before {content: "\2192 \0020";}` to `.sub:before {content: "\2192 \0020";}`

Comment: Thank you for your solution. There is a space for the arrow elements: https://i.imgur.com/PNHr9A8.png